# When computing the derivative of $x^2 + y^2$, why does $y$ become $0$?

Tags: derivatives

The derivative of

$$x^2 + y^2$$ is $$2x$$

I figured it out by using the calculator.

Why does $y$ become $0$? Do I always think $y$ as $0$ in that situation?

Comment: If it's a partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ then $y$ is considered constant.

Comment: When you derive with respect to a variable, say $x$, all other variable become "dummy numbers". In this case, simply imagine that $y^2 = 42$ and you therefore take the derivative of $x^2 + 42$ which is indeed $2x$.

Comment: You need to say what you are differentiating with respect to.  Finding the partial derivative with respect to $y $ of $f (x,y)=x^2+y^2$ yields  $2y $

Answer (score 1):

If you have a function like:

$$f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$$

then the derivative is a vector called Gradient  and it is given by

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\begin{pmatrix}
2x\\
2y
\end{pmatrix}$$

on the other hand if you take a partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ then

$$\partial _{x}f(x,y) =2x$$

on that case you consider $y$ as a constant.

Comment: @tom: you are very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

$2x$ is the **partial** derivative of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ when you look into infinitesimal variations of $x$; in fact in this case you are not concerned about the value of $y$ as you are just focused into the $x$ variable.

On the other hand, the partial derivative of $f(x,y)$ with respect to $y$ is $2y$